# Understand TableView and UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift

I Need some help to understand how can I filter a information in Uitableview with UISegmentedControl.  I have a UITabeView with data that contain two different data,  Rec and Dat . I want to load ALL data when start application and separate Deb and Rec when user choose in UISegmentedControl. When I start application I populate 3 Array alls,  recs and dats. I show the array alls, and want to change/filter the data when the user change the choose in UisegmentControl. Can you help me please ?

```
@IBAction func filtroDebitoCredito(sender: AnyObject) {

        //when All
        if FiltroControlerTable.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
           // tableView.reloadData()  ???
        }
        //When Creds
        if FiltroControlerTable.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
          //  ???

        }
        //Debs
        if FiltroControlerTable.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
           // ??? 
        }
```

Tks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are already there. Your table view displays model data. So when the user changes the value of the segmented control, switch to the correct set of model data and, exactly as you say, tell the table to `reloadData()`. What I would do is have *four* arrays: `model`, `all`, `recs`, and `dats`. The table, let us say, always displays `model`. So the segmented control would copy, let us say, `recs` into `model` and tell the table view to reload!

Comment: Perfect @matt ! !  I did It and run Perfectly. Tks for  help

Comment: You did all the work @Cauca! I merely showed you that you had already solved the problem. Well done.

Comment: Tks can you see the checkmark now ? I didn't know this ! Tks again

Comment: Cauca, does the UISegmentedControl works normally if you click one index and then the other without doing anything else?